# Pass a Folder and a Variable to Next Macro with Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using Excel VBA.
In the first macro, I have

```
Sub SearchReport()
'code here
Report FileSystem.getFolder(HostFolder)
End Sub
```

Report is the second macro name and I am able to pass the "folder" into this macro

```
Sub Report (Folder)
'code here
End Sub
```

How if I want to pass another variable p which is an integer? I need something like this in the second macro

```
Sub Report (Folder, p)
```

I have no idea on how to declare it in the first macro, so I am here to seek for help. Any effort is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub SearchReport()
    Dim p As Integer
    p = 25
    Report FileSystem.getFolder(HostFolder), p
End Sub
```